# Removing Certain Text from String in PHP

Tags: php, text

I am trying to trim a string in PHP so that I can only get certain text from the String.

I have an email stored to a String for instance some_name@somedomain.com .

How can I remove the text after the '@' so that I would only 'some_name'?

Comment: Why you change your tag?

Comment: Why you no read question and see it says "PHP"?

Comment: @Kushan Sorry, I realized I put the wrong tag after I posted it. Too much of Android and PHP at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you can do :

```
$string = 'some_name@somedomain.com';
$res = explode('@', $string);
echo $res[0];
```

Or you can use regexp, string functions in php ... etc

Comment: hello, how can I convert the res into a string?

Comment: you can assign the first array element to a variable:
`$name = $res[0]; echo $name;`

Answer (score 3):

You should know both ways to do this:

**[substr](http://php.net/substr)**

```
$mail = "some_name@somedomain.com";
echo substr($mail, 0, strpos($mail, '@') );
```

**[explode](http://php.net/explode)**

```
list($name, $domain) = explode('@', $mail);
echo $name;
```

If you don't need the $domain you can skip it:

```
list($name) = explode('@', $mail);
```

More about [list](http://php.net/list).

Demo: http://ideone.com/lbvQF

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'some_name@somedomain.com';
$strpos = strpos($str, "@");
echo $email = substr($str, 0,$strpos);
```

you can try this to get string before @

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`$str1 = "Hello World";`

`echo trim($str1,"World");`

Answer (score -1):

You could try split using regex and the @ symbol. This will return two Strings which you can then use just to acquire the 'some_name'.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Was this question originally tagged with "java" or something?  cause few of the answers so far have anything to do with PHP...

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "some_name@somedomain.com";
String name = s.substring(0,s.indexOf("@");
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I changed the tags! But this is useful as well! Thanks!